# Pandas csv format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading records and write them as csv file using pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=columns)
```

They are stored as this csv format

```
column1, column2
1,{'Stars': 1.0, 'BaseScore': 0.18564370805147765, 'Score': 0.12995059563603434, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 3}
```

whereas I want them to be stored as this csv format. What would I need to change in

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=columns)
```

I have tried `double_quotes=True`

```
column1, column2
1,"{""Stars"":2.0,""BaseScore"":0.31373923048181962,""Score"":0.31373923048181962,""Version"":1,""CheckType"":3}
```

Comment: So every entry column1 is an `int` and every entry in column2 is this bracket-thing (JSON)?

Comment: Okay so you want to store many JSON-dict's via pandas? Why don't you put all JOSN-dict's into a List and store it via the json-module?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `df['column2'] = df['column2'].map(json.dumps)` before writing to csv?